# Question about Inner product and Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

If we start with an inner product on a vector space, there is a unique induced norm on it, defined by

$$|| x ||=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$$

With this definition, many inequalities and theorems can be derived.

My question is: If we choose another definition of norm, would the norm and the inner product be consistent? My guess is that the vector space would still make sense, but we will lose a lot of nice properties since there is no relationship between thr inner product and the norm.

Comment: An inner-product space would not change if you change "the" norm. A normed vector space would not change if you change the inner product. They are separate things. With one of these, there is often a natural association to the other, so if you're changing things up make it clear.

Comment: @DavidP Thanks for clearing it up. I was just trying to have a clearer idea about the concepts before go on studying, otherwise I may get confused once the setting changes.